# HTML <ul> | Change particular <li> color onclick and other <li> in the same <ul> to default color

Tags: jquery, css

I want to have 5 lists such than when any of them is clicked, it turns to green **and** turn the other lists to black if any of them is green.

Here's my list:

[image: list]

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have written the jquery. However, it's not concise, as I have to select `$('#menu li:first-child').. and $('#menu li:nth-child(2 to 5)')..`

Please check out the **demo** and let me know the easiest way you have to get this done

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/t7L6d7b4/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you do it:

```
var $li = $('#menu li').click(function() {
    $li.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

with this CSS for selected item:

```
li.selected {
    color: green;
}
```

Don't ever use `css` method for such things, this is **very** obtrusive approach which requires you to modify JS code when you want to change styling. If tomorrow you decide to add a background image to selected item, what will you have to do if you go with `.css` approach? You should use classes for this, in this case you write JS once and forget about this. Styles are for CSS, UI logic is for JS.

Here is a **demo**:

```js
var $li = $('#menu li').click(function() {
    $li.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
li.selected {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the words of wisdom. I'll definitely keep that in mind to separate CSS for Styles and JS for UI Logic

Answer (score 3):

You can just do

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('li').css('color','black');
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t7L6d7b4/2/) The above is simple, but you can create classes and add/remove it using addClass/removeClass.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it with `addClass/removeClass` but this works +1

Comment: @Paulie_D That's a great solution too! Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `$('li').css('color','black');` be just ``$(this).css('color','black');``? Or even using a chain, like `$(this).css('color', 'green').css('color', 'black');`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is this:

```js
$("ul > li").on("click", function(){
    $("ul li").css("color", "black");
    $(this).css("color", "green");   
});
```

```css
li{
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code without using any library or frameworks. You can acheive this using javascript.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="active">one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Script goes here ....

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var elems = document.querySelector(".active");
  if(elems !==null){
   elems.classList.remove("active");
  }
 e.target.className = "active";
}
```

css goes here....

```
li.active {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS too! Like this. Behavior  - On clicking it will show green, then it will turn back to black.

```css
li:active{
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The `:active` pseudo-class is not the same as a click. It's a `mousedown` only event and not persistent.

Comment: I agree, i have updated my post, just in case, OP might be interested in this solution, i posted this.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with jquery version 2.1.1, Please try this

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu li', function(){
   $('.#menu li').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

And add this in CSS file.

```
#menu li.selected {
   background-color: rgb(2, 95, 191);
}
```