# Change background of <li> elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am new at javascript. I want to change background of

elements from white to red when I click on it. After clicking another

element want to convert to red this element and change to white the rest. I success but last

was not affected.

```js
function func(li) {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.backgroundColor == "red") {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      console.log('W');
    } else {
      li.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      console.log('W');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">birinci</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">ikinci</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">ucuncu</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">dorduncu</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think this is the same you are searching for.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317520/html-ul-change-particular-li-color-onclick-and-other-li-in-the-same-ul]

Comment: @Omikabira Not tagged jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try this version

1. Using event listeners
2. Listening to any click on the UL instead of each LI
3. Unobtrusive (not using inline event handlers)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click",function(e) { // click the UL
    var clickedObject = e.target;
    if (clickedObject.tagName == "LI") { // was it an LI
      document.querySelectorAll(".reng").forEach(function(li) { // reset all
        li.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      });
      clickedObject.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // color the clicked LI
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="reng">birinci</li>
  <li class="reng">ikinci</li>
  <li class="reng">ucuncu</li>
  <li class="reng">dorduncu</li>
</ul>
```

If you wanted to toggle the clicked LI:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click",function(e) { // click the UL
    var clickedObject = e.target;
    if (clickedObject.tagName == "LI") { // was it an LI
      var col = clickedObject.style.backgroundColor;
      document.querySelectorAll(".reng").forEach(function(li) { // reset all
        li.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      });
      clickedObject.style.backgroundColor = col == "red" ? "white" : "red"; // toggle the clicked LI
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="reng">birinci</li>
  <li class="reng">ikinci</li>
  <li class="reng">ucuncu</li>
  <li class="reng">dorduncu</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would simply do this, there is no need of condition checking simply remove red background from all li and put red background on clicking li object.

```js
function func(li){
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";     
    }
    li.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">birinci</li>
    <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">ikinci</li>
    <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">ucuncu</li>
    <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">dorduncu</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` to make all li white then turn the clicked one to red

```js
function func(li) {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  a.forEach((e) => e.style.backgroundColor = "white")
  li.style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">birinci</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">ikinci</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">ucuncu</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">dorduncu</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to have inline event handlers

Comment: `if (li.style.backgroundColor == "white")` is always true

Answer (score 0):

```js
function func(li) {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.backgroundColor == "red") {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }     
  }
  li.style.backgroundColor = "red";    
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">birinci</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">ikinci</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">ucuncu</li>
  <li class="reng" onclick="func(this)">dorduncu</li>
</ul>
```

i just changed your code. and it's working now.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code is badly written.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  var i;
// we iterate over all LI elements
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if(x[i].style.backgroundColor == "red"){
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      console.log('W');
      }
// if given by index LI element backgroundColor is not "red" 
// then LI clicked element backgroundColor is set to "red"
// so at first if you click on ANY (including LAST) element 
// from list the LAST element property is at first set to "red" 
// - which is not visible because in next 
// for(..) iteration this LAST element is set to 'white' !!!
// etc etc
     else {
        li.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        console.log('W');
}
```