# How can I change the background of my li element upon clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I came across this post: [HTML <ul> | Change particular <li> color onclick and other <li> in the same <ul> to default color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317520/html-ul-change-particular-li-color-onclick-and-other-li-in-the-same-ul)

And it looks like what I'm looking for; but I was a bit confused as to how I'd do the same in a rails app (that's also using react/redux). In the rails apps that I've worked on so far, I have yet to see any jquery in them so I'm not sure where/how I'd implement the same idea. Any help is appreciated!

I thought about using the `onClick` event for the li elements, and then making a function to add a class to the clicked element/remove the class from all other li elements, but I'm not sure if this is on the right track.

// this is my component rendering the ul element

```
import React from 'react';
import TrackIndexItem from './track_index_item';

const TrackDetail = ({ tracks }) => (
  <ul>
    { tracks.map(track => <TrackIndexItem key={ track.id } track={track} />) } 
  </ul>
);

export default TrackDetail;
```

// this is my component rendering the li elements

```
import React from 'react';

const TrackIndexItem = ({ track }) => ( 
  <li>
    <div className="track-info">
      <i className="music-note-icon"></i>
      <div className="track-text">
        <p>{track.title}</p> 
        <p>{track.artist} • {track.album}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
);

export default TrackIndexItem;
```

// this is my css for the li elements:

```
li {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        padding: 0 20px;

        .track-info {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          position: relative;

          .music-note-icon {
            position: absolute;
            content: image_url('music-note-icon.png');
            width: 10px;
            height: 15px;
            top: 20px;
          }

          .track-text {
            margin-left: 25px;

            p {
              font-family: 'ProximaNova-Regular';
            }

            p:first-of-type {
              font-size: 18px;
              color: $white;
            }

            p:last-of-type {
              font-size: 16px;
              color: $gray;
              margin-top: -15px;
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I would make use of `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. For example, if the class was called, "clicked", you could remove it from any `li` elements that have it and then add it to the one that was clicked upon.

Comment: Ah ok, that's what I was thinking as well. Would it be a good idea to put those into a function that I call using the `onClick` event for the li tag?

Comment: You can do that. I think it's easy enough to just include it in an anonymous function for the Click callback.

Comment: You can also just add the `onClick()` to your JSX when you are creating the `<li>` tags. I've added that to my example below.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous Function Example

```js
$(function() {
  $("li").click(function(e) {
    $(".clicked").removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  });
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>
    <div className="track-info">
      <i className="music-note-icon"></i>
      <div className="track-text">
        <p>{track.title}</p>
        <p>{track.artist} • {track.album}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div className="track-info">
      <i className="music-note-icon"></i>
      <div className="track-text">
        <p>{track.title}</p>
        <p>{track.artist} • {track.album}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div className="track-info">
      <i className="music-note-icon"></i>
      <div className="track-text">
        <p>{track.title}</p>
        <p>{track.artist} • {track.album}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

This specifically selects all `clicked` class items, removes the class, and then adds it to the targeted element.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense; and for the anonymous function, where in my app (which file) should I put it in? I'm guessing it shouldn't be in the HTML or CSS; would I place it in the same file as the component that renders the li elements?

Comment: @Karen in your HTML or if you have a JavaScript file that you are loading in, that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure JS version that I was creating at the same time. It's also available on CodePen: https://codepen.io/edlucas/pen/LYEwjxO

Since you are using React, you could do something a bit different than the code example and add the onClick() directly in your JSX.

```
const TrackIndexItem = ({ track }) => ( 
  <li onClick={e => highlight(e)}>
    ...
  </li>
);
```

In that case, you could move the selectors into the highlight function (the only remaining place those variables would be used).

```
function highlight(e) {
    const list = document.getElementById('trackList');
    const items = list.querySelectorAll('li');

    targetItem = e.target;
    ...
}
```

These functions could all all be added into your TrackIndexItem component file. `removeClass()` and `addClass()` are generic enough to move to a file containing helper/utility functions and imported into your TrackIndexItem file, if you prefer.

**Working code snippet:**

```js
// Using pure JS, no jQuery
const list = document.getElementById('trackList');
const items = list.querySelectorAll('li');

items.forEach((item) => {
 item.onclick = (e) => highlight(e);
});

function highlight(e) {
 targetItem = e.target;
 
 // Remove the class from all items
 items.forEach((item) => {
  removeClass(item, 'active');
 });
 
 // Add the class to the "clicked" item
 addClass(targetItem, 'active');
}

function removeClass(item, classVal) {
 classList = item.className.split(' ');
 item.className = classList.filter(item => item !== classVal).join(' ');
}

function addClass(item, classVal) {
 classList = item.className.split(' ');
 
 // Only add the class if it's not in the list
 if (!classList.includes(classVal)) {
  classList.push(classVal);
 }
 item.className = classList.join(' ');
}
```

```css
li {
 width: 100px;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li.bordered {
 border: 1px solid green;
}

li.active {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <ul id="trackList">
   <li class="bordered test">Test 1</li>
   <li class="bordered">Test 2</li>
   <li class="bordered">Test 3</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah thank you for the clarification! I'll give it a try!

Comment: I haven't gotten to try it yet but I'll let you know/accept an answer as soon as I do! Got stuck on a couple of other bugs aha